# PHP 10000 concurrent calls and MYSQL query wait time and slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concurrency, database-performance

I have a very simple query that inserts every api call to messageRequest table. it can go maximum of 1000 requests or more per second.

for example, http://myapplication.com/sendMessage.php?phone=123&gsm=mobitel&message=helloworld

assume, anyone with our app in mobile will call this URL. and when i make like 1000 calls via

ab -n 1000 -c 10 "http://myapplication.com/sendMessage.php?phone=123&gsm=mobitel&message=helloworld"

The query is `insert into messageRequest values(null, phone, gsm, message);`

it works fine, but the issue is while this many concurrent calls are there, when i try to use my activity log page in this URL http://myapplication.com/apiLogs.php to see how many SMS api calls are received in last 30 minutes.

It just queries `SELECT count(*) from messageRequest where created_at > '2016-10-01 12:01:00'`

it takes like 100 seconds to return result. and when i stopped making concurrent calls via `ab -n command` its working fine. so i assumed when 1000 concurrent calls happens and a record is inserted for every call, MYSQL table messageRequest is getting locked.

to avoid this problem,

i changed this to multiple sessions, for example to `sendMessage.php` i made it run with user1, and for the apiLogs.php i made it with user2. so 2 diff sessions can access the same table to read and write simultaneously but that didnt help too.

**sendMessage.php**

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user1');
define('DB_PASS', '');
```

**apiLogs.php**

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user2');
define('DB_PASS', '');
```

i am confused how to make it work without any waiting time while so many concurrent calls?

**Update**

sendMessage.php code

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user1');
define('DB_PASS', 'user1');

 mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 mysql_select_db('smsApp');


     mysql_query(
        "insert into messageRequest values (
            NULL,
            '{$_REQUEST['phone']}',
            '{$_REQUEST['gsm']}',
            '{$_REQUEST['message']}',
            '{$_REQUEST['text']}',
            now()
            );
        "
    );
```

And i am making concurrent request with this command

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 "http://myapplication.com/sendMessage.php?phone=123&gsm=mobitel&message=helloworld&text=123"
```

And while is running, i am trying to view this page apiLogs.php (source code is below)

```
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'user2');
    define('DB_PASS', 'user2');

     mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     mysql_select_db('smsApp');

$30m_ago = new DateTime("30 minutes ago");
$s = $30m_ago->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from messageRequest where created_at > '$s'");

$response['last_30_min_sms_count'] = current(mysql_fetch_row($result));

echo json_encode($response)."\n";
```

Comment: And there is 1 million record already in the `messageRequest` table.

Comment: The only thing you can do is optimize your code, or upgrade the hardware on which it's run.

Comment: @Thomas can u give a example for optimizing the code as in what aspect?

Comment: not without the code, but 1000 database queries are still a lot.

Comment: @Thomas its not 1000 database queries, its API calls. check the updated question please with source code.its very simple code. only a simple db insert.

Comment: if the api calls the database, and the api is called 1000 times, then the database is also called 1000 times.

Comment: @Thomas yes but its unavoidable. heavy traffic messaging app. source code is posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  That way, the table won't be locked.

Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` API, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

"Don't queue it, just do it."  That is, it may be significantly faster to simply perform the task rather than going through a queue.

The code snippet is subject to "SQL Injection".

Do have `INDEX(created_at)`.  That `SELECT` can run entirely in the index.

Instead of the `DateTime` package, you could simply say `SELECT ... WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`.

**More**

With InnoDB, I suggest `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` to cut back significantly on the I/O caused by 1000 separate `INSERTs` per second.

Comment: I am already using innoDB and i have improved the code to use PDO but still when 1000 request per second and during that time when i view the apiLogs.php its very slow

Comment: Do you have the index?  For a million-row table, that will be very important for the `SELECT`.  Without it, the entire million rows will be scanned every time.  This chews up CPU cycles.

Comment: @Rici yes, there is index for `created_at`

Comment: is it a good practice to have a summary table to just save only this count? ex: `messageRequestSummary` and make apiLogs.php to get count from new table? `SELECT count(*) from `messageRequestSummary`  where created_at > '$s'` and use a trigger a to update the count in messageRequestSummary

Comment: I would build the Summary table with a granularity of hour or day.  Then you can roll up into weeks or months.  Having only a single count is unusual, but OK.  Some notes on [_Summary Tables_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/) .

Comment: Also, see "More" in my answer.